# Can a single player who's been knocked back recover ground?

Tags: the-legend-of-korra

In Pro-bending, if one team knocks all opposing players out of the neighboring zone, they can advance.  What happens if one of the players on the pressing team is behind the others?

e.g.

- One player from Team 1 is forced into Zone 2
- All players from Team 2 are knocked into their Zone 2
- ?

Comment: the answer probably lie in this video : http://korranation.tumblr.com/post/19586633139/bryan-konietzko-creator-of-a-tla-and-the-legend

Comment: @DavRob60 I watched that previously; he discussed how the team recovers ground, but not what happens if they're 'staggered'.

Answer (score 1):

Once a player is knocked back, I'm pretty sure he(or she) is almost forever in that round, stuck there. In a sense, If I got knocked back to zone 2, but then my team-mates knock the other team to their zone two, my team mates can then move up into enemy zone 1, and I get to move back into the starting zone 1.

```
[E3  |  E2  |  E1  |  Z1  |  Z2  |  Z3]
```

Badguys E1     team Z1     Im here in Z2

Then bad guys to E2  Team to E1 and me to Z1

I hope this made sense lol

Answer (score 0):

**We don't know yet**.

Honestly we don't know what would happen in this situation as it hasn't been laid out in the show yet. But here's a break down of the 'Gaining Terriatory' section on the Avatar Wiki

> At the start of the match, each team must remain within the first zone nearest to the center of the arena. *Once a competitor is knocked into zone two by someone from the opposing team, he or she must stay there and cannot return to zone one.* The same rules apply if he or she crosses over to zone three. A player that is completely knocked off the ring cannot return that round.

So as you said, once someone is knocked into zone two they must stay there and remain in zone two.

> If all three members from one team are knocked back into zone two, a green light appears in the center line and the opposing team can advance into zone one on the other side; if they do this, they cannot move backwards into their own zone.

In light of this last rule, I can see the situation going like this:

Player 1 on team A, is knocked into zone 2. Team A knocks team B back to their respective zone 2.

So Either Player 1A is blocked from moving forwards for that round or player 1A can move forwards a zone, or they can rejoin their team mates in their new zone (1B). I'd imagine it works as the middle suggestion but honestly, I don't know which rule takes precedent and *I don't think we can know yet*.